# LIST return in nested cond

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I don't understand why my program is behaving as it does.

```
(defvar A '((X Y Z) (J L O P) (G W U))

(defvar Z '(X W D U G))

(defvar STOP 'G)

(defun ADD_to_Z(A2)
  (prog()
    (cond
        ((equal (Member_Of_Z (list A2)) 0) )
        (t (setq Z (append Z (list A2))) )
    )
  )
)

(defun Member_of_Z(cdr_A1)

(prog(n temp)
   (setq n 0)
   (setq temp cdr_A1)
   repeat
   (cond
     ((null temp) (return n))
     ((null (member (car temp) Z) ) (setq n (+ n 1)) (setq temp (cdr temp)))
     (t (setq n (+ n 0)) (setq temp (cdr temp)))
   )
   (go repeat)
)
)



(defun TEST(A)

(prog(A1 A2)

      (cond
          ((null A ) (return 'Fail))
          (t (setq A1 (car A)) (setq A (cdr A)) (setq A2 (car A1)) 
             (cond 
              ((equal (Member_Of_Z (cdr A1)) 0) 
               (cond
                 ((equal A2 STOP) (return 'SUCCESS))
                 (t (ADD_to_Z A2) (setq A (cdr A)) (TEST A) )
               )
              )
              (t (TEST A)  )
             )
          )
      ) 

    )
    )
```

Goal of the functions :
- `Member_of_Z` will verify if **all elements** of `cdr A1` belong to Z. If they do , it will return 0 (some other number else otherwise). **This is what is not happening** It was suppose to return SUCCESS when A is equal to `((G W U))`

- `ADD_to_Z` will add A2 to Z when `Member_Of_Z` does not return 0

Problem : Not only A seems to be never modified (at the end of the function TEST, A is still equal to its original value set by `defvar` even though I'm modifying it with `(setq A (cdr A))`. Also SUCCESS is never returned.

Could you help me ?

Comment: Modifying literals is undefined behavior (or implementation defined, never remeber) in CL. If you want to modify a list use (list ...elements) to define it instead of quote.

Comment: @PuercoPop It doesn't seem to be modifying the literal data, it's just assigning new values to `A` (or it's trying to, but the function parameter shadows the binding).

Comment: There are a lot of logical errors and the style is more like Fortran than CL, The example is not runnable as you have left out functions it uses and since you haven't given an example usage with expected result I have no idea what this is suppose to do. `defvar` variables lack their `*earmuffs*` so they are indistinguishable with lexical variables. When you are `setq`-ing `A` it's the parameter in `test` and not the misnamed global you are changing.

Comment: @Sylwester Thanks. I added the missing functions..so that the code is runnable. What are my errors ? How should I correct them ?

Comment: @jkiiski Exactly. What should I do ?  I added more code so that it's runnable. Could you take a look at it ?

Comment: @PuercoPop Thanks. I'll keep that in mind when altering my code. Btw I added more functinos so tha the code is runnable. Could you take a look at it ?

Comment: You need to write it more functional eg. `(defun count-missing-in-z (lst) (count-if-not (lambda (e) (member e *z*)) lst))`. Do you see a global in that function? `*z*` right?

Comment: @Sylwester Yup I see `*z*`. Are you implying that to access and modify my globals from wiithin my functions I should declare them in `defvar` with earmuffs `* ... *` ?

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: use standard formatting (repairing the first toplevel form).

```
(defvar A '((X Y Z) (J L O P) (G W U)))

(defvar Z '(X W D U G))

(defvar STOP 'G)

(defun ADD_to_Z (A2)
  (prog ()
    (cond ((equal (Member_Of_Z (list A2)) 0))
          (t (setq Z (append Z (list A2)))))))

(defun Member_of_Z (cdr_A1)
  (prog (n temp)
    (setq n 0)
    (setq temp cdr_A1)
    repeat
    (cond ((null temp) (return n))
          ((null (member (car temp) Z) ) (setq n (+ n 1)) (setq temp (cdr temp)))
          (t (setq n (+ n 0)) (setq temp (cdr temp))))
    (go repeat)))

(defun TEST (A)
  (prog (A1 A2)
    (cond ((null A ) (return 'Fail))
          (t (setq A1 (car A))
             (setq A (cdr A))
             (setq A2 (car A1))
             (cond ((equal (Member_Of_Z (cdr A1)) 0)
                    (cond ((equal A2 STOP) (return 'SUCCESS))
                          (t (ADD_to_Z A2) (setq A (cdr A)) (TEST A) )))
                   (t (TEST A)))))))
```

Step 2: use standard naming.

```
(defvar *a* '((x y z) (j l o p) (g w u)))

(defvar *z* '(x w d u g))

(defvar *stop* 'g)

(defun add-to-z (a2)
  (prog ()
    (cond ((equal (member-of-z (list a2)) 0))
          (t (setq *z* (append *z* (list a2)))))))

(defun member-of-z (cdr-a1)
  (prog (n temp)
    (setq n 0)
    (setq temp cdr-a1)
    repeat
    (cond ((null temp) (return n))
          ((null (member (car temp) *z*)) (setq n (+ n 1)) (setq temp (cdr temp)))
          (t (setq n (+ n 0)) (setq temp (cdr temp))))
    (go repeat)))

(defun test (a)
  (prog (a1 a2)
    (cond ((null a) (return 'fail))
          (t (setq a1 (car a))
             (setq a (cdr a))
             (setq a2 (car a1))
             (cond ((equal (member-of-z (cdr a1)) 0)
                    (cond ((equal a2 *stop*) (return 'success))
                          (t (add-to-z a2) (setq a (cdr a)) (test a))))
                   (t (test a)))))))
```

Step 3: get rid of PROG.

```
(defvar *a* '((x y z) (j l o p) (g w u)))

(defvar *z* '(x w d u g))

(defvar *stop* 'g)

(defun add-to-z (a2)
  (cond ((equal (member-of-z (list a2)) 0))
        (t (setq *z* (append *z* (list a2))))))

(defun member-of-z (cdr-a1)
  (let ((n 0)
        (temp cdr-a1))
    repeat
    (cond ((null temp) (return n))
          ((null (member (car temp) z)) (setq n (+ n 1)) (setq temp (cdr temp)))
          (t (setq n (+ n 0)) (setq temp (cdr temp))))
    (go repeat)))

(defun test (a)
  (cond ((null a) (return 'fail))
        (t (let ((a1 (car a))
                 (a (cdr a))
                 (a2 (car a1)))
             (cond ((equal (member-of-z (cdr a1)) 0)
                    (cond ((equal a2 *stop*) (return 'success))
                          (t (add-to-z a2) (setq a (cdr a)) (test a))))
                   (t (test a)))))))
```

Step 4: replace hand-rolled loop with a structured one.

```
(defvar *a* '((x y z) (j l o p) (g w u)))

(defvar *z* '(x w d u g))

(defvar *stop* 'g)

(defun add-to-z (a2)
  (cond ((equal (member-of-z (list a2)) 0))
        (t (setq *z* (append *z* (list a2))))))

(defun member-of-z (cdr-a1)
  (let ((n 0)
        (temp cdr-a1))
    (loop :for element :in temp
          :unless (member element *z*)
          :do (incf n))
    n))

(defun test (a)
  (cond ((null a) (return 'fail))
        (t (let ((a1 (car a))
                 (a (cdr a))
                 (a2 (car a1)))
             (cond ((equal (member-of-z (cdr a1)) 0)
                    (cond ((equal a2 *stop*) (return 'success))
                          (t (add-to-z a2) (setq a (cdr a)) (test a))))
                   (t (test a)))))))
```

Step 5: replace two-clause COND with IF.  Reduce RETURN forms when they are in
tail position anyway (and they don't work like that).

```
(defvar *a* '((x y z) (j l o p) (g w u)))

(defvar *z* '(x w d u g))

(defvar *stop* 'g)

(defun add-to-z (a2)
  (if (equal (member-of-z (list a2)) 0)
      nil
      (setq *z* (append *z* (list a2)))))

(defun member-of-z (cdr-a1)
  (let ((n 0)
        (temp cdr-a1))
    (loop :for element :in temp
          :unless (member element *z*)
          :do (incf n))
    n))

(defun test (a)
  (if (null a)
      'fail
      (let ((a1 (car a))
            (a (cdr a))
            (a2 (car a1)))
        (if (equal (member-of-z (cdr a1)) 0)
            (if (equal a2 *stop*)
                'success
                (progn (add-to-z a2) (setq a (cdr a)) (test a)))
            (test a)))))
```

Step 6: replace loop with simple counting function.

```
(defvar *a* '((x y z) (j l o p) (g w u)))

(defvar *z* '(x w d u g))

(defvar *stop* 'g)

(defun add-to-z (a2)
  (if (equal (member-of-z (list a2)) 0)
      nil
      (setq *z* (append *z* (list a2)))))

(defun member-of-z (cdr-a1)
  (count-if-not (lambda (element)
                  (member element *z*))
                cdr-a1))

(defun test (a)
  (if (null a)
      'fail
      (let ((a1 (car a))
            (a (cdr a))
            (a2 (car a1)))
        (if (equal (member-of-z (cdr a1)) 0)
            (if (equal a2 *stop*)
                'success
                (progn
                  (add-to-z a2)
                  (setq a (cdr a))
                  (test a)))
            (test a)))))
```

At this point, I still have no idea what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you want
to find a list in `*a*` that is completely contained in `*z*`:

```
(defun test (a)
  (find-if (lambda (list)
             (every (lambda (element)
                      (member element *z*))
                    list))
           a))
```

Comment: You could use `SUBSETP` in that last snippet. Maybe `MEMBER-IF` would be better too, since the code seems to be returning a "boolean" (SUCCESS / FAIL).

Comment: Yes there is a missing function in my example that is suppose to call `TEST` on a condition failure. The function checks if `stop` is in `z`, if not it will launch `test` . `test` is suppose to do all it does until it finds a sub-list in   `a` whom elements are all in `z` and the first element (that is its `car`) is equal to `stop`. If this is satisfied, it returns `success`.  My question is : does the stars ` * ...*` ensure the global can be called and overriten ? If I stopped at your step 2 will the code still work  (ie will I be missing only proper Syntax ?)

Comment: just saw https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml#Global_variables_and_constants Svante

Comment: @JasonKrs No, the earmuffs (the "*" each end of the symbol) are only there to make it easy to see that you're dealing with a global dynamic variable or not. If you do that for anything you introduce via `defvar` or `defparameter` and never, ever, do it for anything else, you won't end up in a situation where you shadow something you didn't expect.

Comment: @Vatine So in my case it ensures that when dealing with a global in my function it's not shadowed by a local name of the same type right ? BUT in my case, `test` is not called by the user. Another function calls it. It calls it with the global `*a*`. How can I define `test` like `(defun test(*a*) ....` ? so that test is always called with the current state of global `*a*`

Comment: @JasonKrs You shouldn't use "ear-muffed" symbols in that way. The value of `*a*` is available inside `test` (and can be changed by setting it), but if you use `(defun test (*a*) ...)` you introduce another binding, so any side-effect you do is only visible within `test`. More specifically, it's only visible within the specific invocation of `test` it was done in. If you *really* want to pass data by global state (probably a bad idea, in the general case), use `(defun test () ...)`.

Comment: @Vatine Thank You Vatine